# Ansible : breaking the current loop and continue to next with include_tasks

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook abc.yaml which has task like following.

```
- name: Create Backup Config(s)
      include_tasks:
        file: createBackupconfigSub.yaml
        apply:
          tags:
            - createBackupconfig
      loop: "{{createBkupconfig}}"
      tags: [createBackupconfig,never]
      ignore_errors: yes
```

my other playbook createBackupconfigSub.yaml as a few tasks like this.

```
  - name: Describe task
    set_fact:
      task_description: "Creating backupconfig {{item.name}}"

  - name: Print the task
    debug: var=task_description

  - name: Create Backupconfig
    command: "create-backupconfig abc" 
    register: command_output
      
  - name: Get command output as json
    set_fact:
      jsondata: "{{command_output.stdout | from_json}}"

  - name: Get timestamp from the system
    shell: "date"
    register: tstamp
```

When command, "create-backupconfig abc" fails, the playbook createBackupconfigSub.yaml prints error and stops the execution there without going to the next element in the loop in abc.yaml

If I put ignore_errors in task "Create Backupconfig" the subsequent task "Get command output as json" which uses the output from the previous task also fails and throws error on the screen.

Is there a way where we can skip the next set of tasks after "Create Backupconfig" and continue to the next loop ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rescue block to do that:

```
- name: Create Backupconfig
  block:
  - name: Describe task
    set_fact:
      task_description: "Creating backupconfig {{item.name}}"

  - name: Print the task
    debug: var=task_description

  - name: Create Backupconfig
    command: "create-backupconfig abc"
    register: command_output

  - name: Get command output as json
    set_fact:
      jsondata: "{{command_output.stdout | from_json}}"
  rescue:
    - debug:
        msg: "Error with {{ item.name }}"
```

If there is any failure with an item, it will just run the step in rescue block and will pass to the next item of your list.

Additionally, you can also set a condition on the status (`when: command_output.rc == 0`) of your step `Create Backupconfig` on step which depends on it (here: `Get command output as json`) so your file will look like this:

```
  - name: Describe task
    set_fact:
      task_description: "Creating backupconfig {{item.name}}"

  - name: Print the task
    debug: var=task_description

  - name: Create Backupconfig
    command: "create-backupconfig abc" 
    register: command_output
    ignore_errors: yes
      
  - name: Get command output as json
    set_fact:
      jsondata: "{{command_output.stdout | from_json}}"
    when: command_output.rc == 0
```

Edit: I've updated my answer based on what OP need.

Comment: Sure but what if I have multiple tasks after "Create Backupconfig" , I will then have to put the when "command_output.rc == 0" for each and every task , which I don't want. Is there another way to handle this ?

Comment: Ha I think I see what you mean, what your need is "rescue" block. Let me edit my answer